# Nusach Sefard Tachanun solution

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tachanun

Nusach Sefard begins Tachanun with "Elokenu V'Elokai Avoseinu". At times a person begins saying these words as soon as the Shliach Tzibur completes the repetition of Shemona Esrei, and then as there is a reason not to say Tachanun the Shliach Tzibur begins Kaddish.

What can one do to ascertain they didn't say these names of Hashem in vain if they said this and then no Tachanun is being said?

Comment: They can choose to say [at least some] tachanun anyway. There is never a prohibition to say tachanun (except, arguably, shabbat).

Comment: @DoubleAA - Interesting way of dealing with this. However I wonder if there is a Lamdeinu Chukecha type of answer.

Comment: I realize tachanun isn't too popular, especially among those who daven nusach sefard, but turning an honest mistake into an opportunity to beseech God for something (להתחנן) is probably the healthier spiritual option in general, as opposed to finding some clever loophole. Someone will surely find you that loophole; it's just worth reflecting sometimes on what the cost-benefit actually entails.

Comment: @DoubleAA However one may want to continue with the Minyan and hold along with them.

Comment: So say a very short techina: אֱלֹהֵינוּ וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵינוּ. תָּבוֹא לְפָנֶיךָ תְּפִלָּתֵנוּ וְאַל תִּתְעַלַּם מִתְּחִנָּתֵנוּ. And mean it.

Comment: Perhaps under the circumstances a more appropriate short prayer would be או"א יהי נא דילוגינו עליך אהבה ואל יהי שום מכשול בתפילתי

Comment: @DoubleAA - Like your last suggestion. Sounds like an answer.

Comment: Ideally one should wait before beginning tachanun to ascertain that the minyan is saying tachanun.

Comment: @Rafael Aside from being an unnecessary interruption, that doesn't seem very practical. Sometimes even the chazzan doesn't know till someone yells out they're a groom.